# Apache mod_headers cannot unset header on a path

Tags: apache, http-headers, response-headers, mod-headers, setenvif

I am trying to set a header using mod_headers in Apache in all cases EXCEPT a certain path. I've tried each of the three variations below to do so, but none of them seem to work properly to exclude the path. In ALL cases I get the header for all requests, including those that match the example path, e.g.: http://example.com/charts/24_hour_commodity/450/300

```
<VirtualHost *:8200>
...
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/charts/.*" frameallow
    Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN env=!frameallow
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Or:

```
<VirtualHost *:8200>
...
    Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    <LocationMatch "^/charts">
        Header always unset X-Frame-Options
    </LocationMatch>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Or

```
<VirtualHost *:8200>
...
    Header always set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    <Directory "/full/path/to/charts">
        Header always unset X-Frame-Options
    </Directory>
...
</VirtualHost>

#tried both with and without the 'always' in all configs
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the header is set in the first example or not unset in the following two? Any one working solution would be enough...

UPDATE: 
After reading about order of processing on the Apache site, I tried using  conditional blocks instead. Neither of those work either:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/charts#">
    Header unset X-Frame-Options
</If>
```

Or

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/charts" frameallow
<If "reqenv('frameallow') == 1">
    Header unset X-Frame-Options
</If>
```

So, still broken. Must be something about the Header statements not firing after a certain point in processing. Or the ones int he conditional somehow firing before the main one and being overridden. Cannot find a way to debug it down to the root cause though.

Comment: After much more digging, I see this is unanswered a few other places as well. Including here: 
http://serverfault.com/questions/792728/apache-2-4-header-unset-in-location-does-not-work 
and here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/773913/apache-doesnt-unset-headers
Looks like this is a long-standing problem of some kind, but still trying to get to the root of it. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Responses header with expression

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin * "expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/specialPath$#"
```

this may add header wen the `expr = true`

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html

at the bottom of the section **Header Directive**